# Build multiple environments with a single target and single command(Anding -D and property file)

Tags: ant, build-process, build-automation

I have to create a single command to create multiple(dev|qa|uat) war/ear.
Something like :

```
ant -f build.xml -Denv=dev|qa|uat -propertyfile= devProp|qaProp|uatProp 
  -Dstage.dir=devdir|qadir|uatdir
```

I already have different properties file, different staging, deploying target for each environment. I also have different .cmd files to build each of them separately.

What I am stuck at is: How do I build them all in one go?

Comment: Can't you use 3 task with 3 differebt sets of props ? And then execute a single task depending on each of the 3 (in order to build everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<subant />` instruction in your target.

Write down a new ant script (namely master.xml), assuming that your original build is in script build.xml, you can have something like:

```
<target name="build-all">
   <subant target="build-prod">
     <fileset dir="." includes="build.xml"/>
     <propertyset ......../> <!-- properties for the prod build -->
   </subant>
   <subant target="build-dev">
     <fileset dir="." includes="build.xml"/>
     <propertyset ......../> <!-- properties for the dev build -->
   </subant>
</target>
```